# Group by date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm having a problem with grouping in SQL Server.

I have a `datetime` column but I want to group only by date,

Here's my code

```
SELECT ProductCode,
       ProductName,
       ProductType,
       UnitPrice,QTY,
       Amount,
       (convert(varchar, TransactionDate, 101) )AS sTransactionDate
FROM DailyTransactions 
GROUP BY TransactionDate, ProductCode,
          ProductName,ProductType,UnitPrice,QTY,Amount
```

RESULT:

`2/17/2012` appears three times because it has different times ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a quick way of grouping your results by date:

```
SELECT  
   ProductCode,ProductName,ProductType,UnitPrice,QTY,Amount,(convert(varchar, TransactionDate, 101) )AS sTransactionDate
   FROM DailyTransactions 
   GROUP BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, TransactionDate), 0), ProductCode,ProductName,ProductType,UnitPrice,QTY,Amount
```

In this case we are getting the difference between the start of the day and the time in the date and then removing it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
GROUP BY
  DATEPART(year, TransactionDate),
  DATEPART(month, TransactionDate),
  DATEPART(day, TransactionDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to display only one result, why don't you use `DISTINCT`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductCode, ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ProductCode
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, your GROUP BY must appear somewhere in your select.  You are already converting TransactionDate to a 'date only' string, though DATEADD and DATEDIFF together are actually more efficient.

Hence, simply GROUP BY the same format:

```
SELECT ProductCode,
       ProductName,
       ProductType,
       UnitPrice,QTY,
       Amount,
       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, TransactionDate), 0) AS sTransactionDate
FROM DailyTransactions 
GROUP BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, TransactionDate), 0), ProductCode,
          ProductName,ProductType,UnitPrice,QTY,Amount
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CHAR(10) instead of varchar when applying your convert. You shouldn't ever declare char/varchar without length. In this case you aren't truncating enough characters because this is a varchar(30) whereas you really only care about the first 10 characters. Also, your group by should include an identical convert.